# ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '<...>' for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, build, beta, xcode-command-line-tools, macos-monterey

I'm getting the following error when I try to build one of my projects:

```
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
```

I've looked at other questions+answers online, most of which are solved by changing/upgrading Xcode Command Line Tools. However, I'm on MacOS Monterey (the beta version) and it won't let me downgrade my CLT. I also can't downgrade my OS without wiping my entire disk apparently, something I am not too keen to do, even with a backup. I know, big learning experience for me.

Is there anything I can do besides wait for the CLT for this OS to be updated at some undefined time in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but a relatively easy workaround could be to install a working version of mac OS somewhere else. You could partition your drive and install a stable version of or you could install it on a bootable external drive.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891

EDIT: After more research it appears this is firmly an issue of compatibility not an issue with the project itself. Easiest solution in my opinion would be to create a separate install with a stable, compatible version of both xcode and mac os. Alternatavily it does seem like previous versions of xcode can be installed along side newer versions. I don't have a beta of mac os running to test this. https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ downloads are here and you will need a dev account

Hope this helps